# Is there a way how to adjust HTML generated by xPage from document rich text field?

Tags: xpages

Is there a way how to adjust HTML generated by xPage from document rich text field? I have q document from which the rich text field content is displayed on xPage using computed text control. Solution works nice except, that xPages engine generates strange HTML from the rich text field. When displaying page on web using standard form, all texts written by default font and default size doesn't contain  markup arround so on could use CSS to style it. Not this way in xPages. Everything have  tag around and its not funny seeing generated font tag around the div tag :-(

```
<div class="tcl-columns3-in">
  <font size="2" face="sans-serif"></font>
  <font size="2" face="sans-serif">
      <b>Header text ...</b>
  </font>
  <font size="2" face="sans-serif">
     <div class="tcl-box-outlined">
        text ...<br>
     </div>
  </font>
</div>
```

Is there a way how to get rid of  out of generated HTML?. I looked to html filtering option with ASF filter but it requires to adjust settings on filesystem, which not option for me ...

Comment: I think you have to explain more, what do you want? Get rid of the <font or do you mean that some information isn't generated as is should?

Comment: exactly, HTML is generated by different way. It's not the same as it was with native Domino engine.

Comment: Provide your CODE snippet PLEASE!!!!!

Comment: Not sure how to create code snippet here. I have a notes document with richtext field with some formated text content and on xpage there is a computede text control that displays the field value (disabled escaping) HTML output in browser contains <font /> tags all around. But as I understand this is how its working and I cant adjust it ... I understand that output is different from native http (displaying using notes form on web) simply because its different technology.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of steps you narrow down your problem. RichText -> MIME -> RichText is not a problem free relationship. As [Carl pointed out](http://www.iminstant.com/iminstant/iminstant.nsf/d6plinks/ctyr-7h6s6r), you can have a look at the raw RichText -> Mime conversion result. Does that look OK? Then you could use a [Dijit ContentPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/layout/ContentPane) to pull that content in.

It also depends on what control you use to display the content. You might have different success with textbox and RichText editor. If you look for very high fidelity you either store your RT as mime (a property of a RT field) or use [Coex Edit](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/CoexEdit) a commercial server plug-in

Comment: storing content as MIME does not solve this problem. Just because content is saved with the same stupid <font> tags.

Comment: so the stupid font tags are also present when you use Carl's method showing the native conversion?

Comment: You can use the Filtering capability to remove font tags coming back from the RT editor control... but you really need to explain in more detail where you are stuck

Comment: as David wrote XPages engine adds <font> tags almost everywhere. The native Domino engine does not add <font> tags in many cases. If you have a lot of legacy content it might become broken. So I reckon David's question can be rephrased: "is it possible to force XPages engine to generate HTML by exactly the same way as native Domino engine does?"

Comment: one more thing, that approach with pulling RT content asynchronously via Ajax is good, indeed. However it demands JavaScript. If your mobile device does not support JavaScript, the RT content will not be displayed. This is why it's so important to generate the right HTML on server side.

Comment: and finally, I think I discovered a strange bug a couple of days ago. Let's pretend you have some RT content. It looks as one solid string without formatting. XPages engine wraps this string with <font> tags, as usual. And... surprise, surprise... it inserts a couple of <font> tags right into the middle of our string breaking HTML totally. Really frustrating. If you cut and paste your content back into RT field, this problem disappears. So we can solve it, indeed. But if you have a lot of legacy content it's quite difficult to verify everything.

Comment: The "XPages engine" doesn't do anything. It is the control you are using that renders the information provided by the data source. Provide your XPages source snippet, so we can see what you are doing. You might simply need a different control approach! But it is *your** task to take the guesswork out of the problem. So edit your question with your actual code snippet please

Comment: thank you, Stephan, for all your patience. So my code... <xp:inputRichText value="#{doc.Content}" readonly="true"  disableTheme="true" required="false" htmlFilter="identity"></xp:inputRichText> ...

Comment: ... nothing special, but for a simple string like "Hello World" this code will generate <font size="2" face="sans-serif">Hello World</font> which is a sort of regression comparing to old native Domino engine

Answer (score 0):

use a computedField in your Xapge, and set the value to something like this

```
var rt = document1.getDocument().getFirstItem("Body"); 
return rt.getUnformattedText()
```

using this technique you can also format the content the way you like as it is all text. I use this to display colored and formatted json and xml